# Working Schedule

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

How to create a schedule for workers? For example I want to create a worker with name and how much working hours he need to work. Also I would like to set a specific time for working on each worker, specific time for breaks and start time when they should start working. What I am looking for is this outcome:

```
9:00 Worker 1
10:00 break
10:15 Worker 2
11:15 break
```

and so on until all workers' working time has finished.

---

Current code:

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Main { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Schedule s1 = new Schedule(); 
        s1.addSchedule("John", 120);    // 2hours
        s1.addSchedule("William", 180);  // 3 hours 

        Schedule s;

        ArrayList<String> eventData = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(ScheduleBlock ev : s.getSchedule())
        {
            eventData.add(ev.getStartTime().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":" + ev.getStartTime().get(Calendar.MINUTE) +" " + ev.getTopic() + " (" + ev.getDuration() + ")" );
        }

        System.out.println(eventData);
    }

}
```

---

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Schedule {

    private ArrayList<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<Worker>();
    private ArrayList<ScheduleBlock> schedule = new ArrayList<ScheduleBlock>(); 

    public void addSchedule(String name, int duration){
        workers.add(new Worker(name, duration));
      }

     public List<Worker> getWorkers() { return workers; }
     public List<ScheduleBlock> getSchedule() { return schedule; }


     public void generateStudyPlan(){
        schedule = new ArrayList<ScheduleBlock>();
            for(Worker w : workers){
                    schedule.add(new ScheduleBlock(w.getSubject(), Calendar.getInstance(), w.getDuration()));
                }           
            }        

     public void generateStudyPlan(Calendar startStudy) { }
     public void setBlockSize(int size) { }
     public void setBreakLength(int i) { }
}
```

---

```
public class Worker {
    private String name;
    private int duration;

    public Worker(String name, int duration)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getSubject() { return name; }
    public int getDuration() { return duration; }
}
```

ScheduleBlock class:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class ScheduleBlock {
    private String subject;
    private Calendar startTime;
    private int duration;


    public ScheduleBlock(String subject, Calendar startTime, int duration)
    {
        this.subject = subject;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getTopic(){ return subject; }
    public int getDuration() { return duration; }
    public Calendar getStartTime() { return startTime; }
}
```

I can't add a starttime and set my Arraylist to start from that time. Also I can't set up the breaks

Comment: So whats the problem?

Comment: No offense but where does that upvote come from?

Comment: I can't add a starttime and set my Arraylist to start from that time. Also I can't set up the breaks

Comment: What is the break? is it the duration?

Comment: No duration is the duration that workers should work and break is the interval that is between worker's shifts

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you haven't initialized `Schedule s`

```
    Schedule s;  // hasn't been initialized

    ArrayList<String> eventData = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(ScheduleBlock ev : s.getSchedule())  // you're trying to use s here
```